# overflow:auto wasn't work in IE on my blogger

Tags: html, blogger

overflow:auto wasn't work in IE on my blogger, but it works on chrome, Firefox and so on. I try everything I have searched, but in vain. I use overflow:auto on my code in my blogger post HTML, in IE, it will automatically change line, but i don't want my code to break into two lines, can anyone help me? Thank you very much!!

Comment: try this . `ms-overflow:auto`

Comment: OP can you post some example code?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [in blogger, overflow doesn't work in IE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44691340/in-blogger-overflow-doesnt-work-in-ie)