# in blogger, overflow doesn't work in IE

Tags: html, blogger

here is my blog link http://testt0646t.blogspot.tw/2017/06/test.html

if you open it with chrome or firefox, you can find that scroll works well; however, if you open it with IE, you will find the scroll does not work. I tried search on the internet, but found nothing useful. I thought the reason my be that the HTML syntax, `overflow:auto` doesn't work, can anyone help me with this?

```html
<div style="background: #ffffff; border-width: 0.1em 0.1em 0.1em 0.8em; border: solid gray; overflow: auto; padding: 0.2em 0.6em; width: auto;">
<pre style="line-height: 125%; margin: 0;"><span style="color: #008800; font-weight: bold;">print</span> <span style="background-color: #fff0f0;">'hello world!'</span><span style="color: #008800; font-weight: bold;">print</span> <span style="background-color: #fff0f0;">'hello world!'</span><span style="color: #008800; font-weight: bold;">print</span> <span style="background-color: #fff0f0;">'hello world!'</span><span style="color: #008800; font-weight: bold;">print</span> <span style="background-color: #fff0f0;">'hello world!'</span><span style="color: #008800; font-weight: bold;">print</span> <span style="background-color: #fff0f0;">'hello world!'</span><span style="color: #008800; font-weight: bold;">print</span> <span style="background-color: #fff0f0;">'hello world!'</span><span style="color: #008800; font-weight: bold;">print</span> <span style="background-color: #fff0f0;">'hello world!'</span><span style="color: #008800; font-weight: bold;">print</span> <span style="background-color: #fff0f0;">'hello world!'</span><span style="color: #008800; font-weight: bold;">print</span> <span style="background-color: #fff0f0;">'hello world!'</span><span style="color: #008800; font-weight: bold;">print</span> <span style="background-color: #fff0f0;">'hello world!'</span><span style="color: #008800; font-weight: bold;">print</span> <span style="background-color: #fff0f0;">'hello world!'</span><span style="color: #008800; font-weight: bold;">print</span> <span style="background-color: #fff0f0;">'hello world!'</span><span style="color: #008800; font-weight: bold;">print</span> <span style="background-color: #fff0f0;">'hello world!'</span><span style="color: #008800; font-weight: bold;">print</span> <span style="background-color: #fff0f0;">'hello world!'</span><span style="color: #008800; font-weight: bold;">print</span> <span style="background-color: #fff0f0;">'hello world!'</span><span style="color: #008800; font-weight: bold;">print</span> <span style="background-color: #fff0f0;">'hello world!'</span><span style="color: #008800; font-weight: bold;">print</span> <span style="background-color: #fff0f0;">'hello world!'</span><span style="color: #008800; font-weight: bold;">print</span> <span style="background-color: #fff0f0;">'hello world!'</span>
</pre>
</div>
```

Comment: what's your version of IE?

Comment: i test in IE9,11   both not work

Comment: A google search would reveal that there are answers for that already. Please go through them first

Comment: i have tried add ms-overflow, but in vain

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding `word-wrap:normal` to the `pre` element should resolve the problem. The issue is happening because of the [word-wrap:break-word](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow-wrap) property added by Blogger to the `body` element

```html
<div style="background: #ffffff; border-width: 0.1em 0.1em 0.1em 0.8em; border: solid gray; overflow: auto; padding: 0.2em 0.6em; width: auto;">
<pre style="word-wrap:normal;line-height: 125%; margin: 0;"><span style="color: #008800; font-weight: bold;">print</span> <span style="background-color: #fff0f0;">'hello world!'</span><span style="color: #008800; font-weight: bold;">print</span> <span style="background-color: #fff0f0;">'hello world!'</span><span style="color: #008800; font-weight: bold;">print</span> <span style="background-color: #fff0f0;">'hello world!'</span><span style="color: #008800; font-weight: bold;">print</span> <span style="background-color: #fff0f0;">'hello world!'</span><span style="color: #008800; font-weight: bold;">print</span> <span style="background-color: #fff0f0;">'hello world!'</span><span style="color: #008800; font-weight: bold;">print</span> <span style="background-color: #fff0f0;">'hello world!'</span><span style="color: #008800; font-weight: bold;">print</span> <span style="background-color: #fff0f0;">'hello world!'</span><span style="color: #008800; font-weight: bold;">print</span> <span style="background-color: #fff0f0;">'hello world!'</span><span style="color: #008800; font-weight: bold;">print</span> <span style="background-color: #fff0f0;">'hello world!'</span><span style="color: #008800; font-weight: bold;">print</span> <span style="background-color: #fff0f0;">'hello world!'</span><span style="color: #008800; font-weight: bold;">print</span> <span style="background-color: #fff0f0;">'hello world!'</span><span style="color: #008800; font-weight: bold;">print</span> <span style="background-color: #fff0f0;">'hello world!'</span><span style="color: #008800; font-weight: bold;">print</span> <span style="background-color: #fff0f0;">'hello world!'</span><span style="color: #008800; font-weight: bold;">print</span> <span style="background-color: #fff0f0;">'hello world!'</span><span style="color: #008800; font-weight: bold;">print</span> <span style="background-color: #fff0f0;">'hello world!'</span><span style="color: #008800; font-weight: bold;">print</span> <span style="background-color: #fff0f0;">'hello world!'</span><span style="color: #008800; font-weight: bold;">print</span> <span style="background-color: #fff0f0;">'hello world!'</span><span style="color: #008800; font-weight: bold;">print</span> <span style="background-color: #fff0f0;">'hello world!'</span>
</pre>
</div>
```